# AWS AppSync Nested Resolver - how to reuse arguments from parent

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-resolver

Heyo. I've got an AppSync resolver with a field that is attached to a resolver. The query accepts an argument that is the same argument the inner resolver would need. For the sake of terseness, I'd like to just pass it down from context instead of having to specify it. The datasource for the resolver is a dynamoDB table
Say the schema looks like

```
type Query {
   getThings(key: String!): AResult!
}

type AResult {
   getOtherThings(key: String!): String!
}
```

I *could* construct a query as such

```
query Query {
  getThings(key: "123") {
    getOtherThings(key: "123")
  }
}
```

Which is clumsy and redundant. Ideally, I'd just want to create a query that looks like

```
query Query {
  getThings(key: "123") {
    getOtherThings
  }
}
```

And the resolver can pull `key` from the context of the request and reuse it.
The request template for `getOtherThings` resolver looks like:

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Query",
    "query": {
        "expression" : "key = :key",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":key" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($context.arguments.key)
        }
    }
}
```

But `$context.guments.key` is `null`. As is `$context.args.key` and `$ctx.args.key` and `$ctx.arguments.key`. If I examine the logs from the request when executing `getThings` I can see the expected arguments:

```
{
    "logType": "RequestMapping",
    "path": [
        "getThings"
    ],
    "fieldName": "getThings",
    "context": {
        "arguments": {
            "key": "123"
        },
        "stash": {},
        "outErrors": []
    },
    "fieldInError": false,
    "errors": [],
    "parentType": "Query"
}
```

So I surmise that the context does not persist between the parent resolver (`getThings`) and its child resolver (`getOtherThings`), but I can't make this out from the logs.

Is this even possible - I'm coming up dry on searching through AWS logs

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in `ctx.source`. `ctx.source` is a map of the parent field, so I can grab it from there.

```
{
    "logType": "RequestMapping",
    "path": [
        "getThings"
    ], 
    "source": {
       "key":"123"
    },
    "fieldName": "getThings",
    "context": {
        "arguments": {
            "key": "123"
        },
        "stash": {},
        "outErrors": []
    },
    "fieldInError": false,
    "errors": [],
    "parentType": "Query"
}
```